# Extract contents of Windows executable that is a wrapped jar file?

Tags: java, hex-editors

I've been trying to unwrap a jar file that is in a Windows executable. I tried to open it with 7Zip, but as I expected that didn't work, and going through the executable in a hex editor leads me to believe it was wrapped with exe4j. Is there any way to get the contents of the jar file?

Comment: Are you trying to get the source code of a jar file?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the solution, it turns out exe4j puts the jar file it needs into a user's temporary directory, like [this](https://vgy.me/rh6ZDP.png). I'll leave this up for anyone else who may need to something like this.